# Maven modify package

Tags: java, maven, jaxb2

I'm trying to find a maven plugin that can modify java package declaration in sources, before comilation. To be more specific, sources are generated via jaxb2 plugin and generated packages (based on namespace) are not satisfying my needs, unfortunately i cant modify in this plugin ;/ for example generated is aa.bb.Foo.java  and i want to turn into cc.dd.Foo.java. Thanks to maven shade plugin i'm able to modify only compiled classes but sources stay untouched, so outputs jars are:

- foo.jar - shade modified packages, ready to deploy.
- foo-orginal.jar - jar before shade modification, nothing special here
- foo-sources.jar - sources compatible only with foo-orginal.jar

Any ideas to have compliant foo-sources.jar with foo.jar?

Answer (score 0):

The Maven JAXB2 plugin provides a configuration to specify a custom package name. Maybe that helps you.

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <generatePackage>my.own.packagename</generatePackage>
    ...
</configuration>
```

See here for more information

http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Controllingtheoutput

**Update:**

If you have more than one namespace, you can use a binding file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="1.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="..."
        node="//xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://demo.ws/address']">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="demo.ws.address" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="..."
    node="//xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://demo.ws/name']">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="demo.ws.name" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This binding file can be set in the plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <bindingDirectory>...</bindingDirectory>
    <bindingIncludes>
        <include>*.xjb</include>
    </bindingIncludes>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'm aware of this configuration in jaxb, but it can't help since i have so many classes with same name and there is a conflict when everything is generated in one package. At the end i have to leave jaxb generation to generate classes based on namespace, then modify packages

Comment: Maybe a binding file is what you're looking for. See my updated answer.

Comment: I get rid of binding file before due to many schemas in one project, around 100, file was a little bit mess and hard to maintain due to a one single xsd has to be specified in this file and mapped to package